# Why Parcel does not update my changes in html file?

Tags: javascript, bundle, parceljs

I use Parcel to develop my web app, but there is one problem: when I make changes in my HTML file, I have to delete the Parcel cache and the 'dist' folder. Finally, I need to run the start command, which will update my changes in the HTML through Parcel. Why is this, because when I first started with the Projekt it was not like now!!